# Loading image from Flask's request.files attribute into PIL Image

Tags: python, flask, python-imaging-library

```
image = Image.open(request.files["fullimage"])
```

returns:

> IOError: cannot identify image file

and

```
image = Image.open(request.files["fullimage"].read())
```

returns:

> IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: ''

What's the right way to do this, please?

Comment: Isn't that the first snippet in my post?

Comment: where is the file located ? how large is it ? When you upload the file, what exact text do you see in the form ? Can you share the view code please?

Answer (score 20):

This could work.

`img = Image.open(request.files['file'].stream)`

Maybe it's too late, but hope it would help others who find this.

Answer (score 0):

I knew this would happen: in trying to put together a simple testcase, I have found the problem and fixed it. It was failing because before the line that tries to load it into the Image, I was doing other stuff, including:

```
request.files["fullimage"].read()
```

Without that, it worked fine. Adding:

```
request.files["fullimage"].seek(0)
```

between that and the line that loads it into the Image fixed the problem. I mean, I have another problem now, but I'll post that separately ;-)

Comment: You can read a "file" from `request.files` only **once**. It is a stream, so when you read it, you will empty it. `seek(0)` won't help you.

Comment: That is probably the cause of my next problem, then! Can I take a copy?

Comment: You can save it to a temporary file: http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html - create such a file object and pass it to `save()`.

Comment: Is that the only way? Can't I create an in-memory copy?

Comment: @matthewk: Sure, write it into a `StringIO`/`cStringIO` object.

Comment: And then can I read the data from the StringIO object more than once?